# return the top n most frequently occurring chars and their respective counts in python

Tags: python

how to return the top n most frequently occurring chars and their respective counts # e.g `'aaaaaabbbbcccc'`, `2` should return `[('a', 6), ('b', 4)]` in python

I tried this

```
def top_chars(input, n):
    list1=list(input)
    list3=[]
    list2=[]
    list4=[]
    set1=set(list1)
    list2=list(set1)
    def count(item):
        count=0
        for x in input:
            if x in input:
                count+=item.count(x)
        list3.append(count)
        return count

    list2.sort(key=count)

    list3.sort()
    list4=list(zip(list2,list3))
    list4.reverse()
    list4.sort(key=lambda list4: ((list4[1]),(list4[0])), reverse=True)
    return list4[0:n]
    pass
```

but it doesn't work for the input ("aabc",2)
The output it should give is

```
[('a', 2), ('b', 1)]
```

but the output I get is

```
[('a', 2), ('c', 1)]
```

Comment: You have **six** `a` characters in your first sample, not 5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `collections.Counter()`; it has a `most_common()` method that does **just that**:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter('aaaaaabbbbcccc')
>>> counts.most_common(2)
[('a', 6), ('c', 4)]
```

Note that for both the above input and in `aabc` both `b` and `c` have the same count, and both can be valid top contenders. Because both you and `Counter` sort by count then key in reverse, `c` is sorted before `b`.

If instead of sorting in reverse, you used the *negative* count as the sort key, you'd sort `b` before `c` again:

```
list4.sort(key=lambda v: (-v[1], v[0))
```

Not that `Counter.most_common()` actually uses sorting when your are asking for fewer items than there are keys in the counter; it uses a [`heapq`-based algorithm](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) instead to only get the top N items.

Comment: I did that but still i get the same o/p. U can check <a href="http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def+top_chars(input,n)%3A%0A++++from+collections+import+Counter%0A++++counts%3DCounter(input)%0A++++top_2+%3D+counts.most_common(n)%0A++++print+top_2%0A++++return+top_2%0Apass%0A%0Aassert+%5B('a',+2),+('b',+1),+('c',+1)%5D+%3D%3D+top_chars(%22aabc%22,+3)&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&curInstr=7">this link </a>for details

Comment: @RiteshBhat: When you ask for the top 2, you *never* get 3 items as the output. Instead, in case of a tie, you get as many keys from the tied position as needed to satisfy your top N request, in reverse sorted order.

Comment: Oh yeah i understood what u said and "list4.sort(key=lambda v: (-v[1], v[0))" worked fine thank u

Answer (score 0):

A little harder, but also works:

```
text = "abbbaaaa"

dict = {}
for lines in text:
    for char in lines:
        dict[char] = dict.get(char, 0) + 1

print dict
```

Comment: But using this i will get a dict whose values and keys need to be zipped to form a list. I think this is also good choice :) Thanks btw

Comment: Sorry, can you explain better "to be zipped" , I don't understand all.

Comment: I mean to say that by doing list(zip(dict_values,dict_keys)) i can get the combination of the (keys,values) as a list.

Answer (score 0):

Text="abbbaaaa"
dict={ }
For lines in text:
For chae in lines:
dict[char]=dict.get(char,0)+1
Print dict

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).